# Same Facebook like button over multiple pages?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

What is considered the best method for 'like' buttons (same for twitter and google+) so that multiple pages use the same one?

If i have an article spanned over several pages, it's giving each page a unique like button and i want it to be the same one. I'd also like to try an automated solution if you know of one.

Using wordpress, I'm currently thinking of using a custom field to input the url directly, but that's not as automated as I'd like. What is the solution?

Currently thinking this might be the easiest:

```
<?php
//Attempt to get page one of a reviews url for social bar on extra review pages.
$socialfield=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'social_url', true);
//if isset & not blank else use the_permalink()
$socialfield=(isset($socialfield) && $socialfield!='')?$socialfield:the_permalink();
```

where 'social_url' is the custom field.

then do this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?=$socialfield?>" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I just wish for a more automated method or at the very least confirmation that this is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

when you get the [`like` button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you will get the codes something like this in HTML5 Tab

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Just note the `data-href="http://www.example.com"` attribute,
now what to do, just get the parameter from the url something like `http://www.example.com/post/first-post/` and set this value in `data-href` attribute.

Comment: the problem is it's dynamically placing url's and i don't want to do it manually if i can.

in place of the url, i'm currently using the_permalink(). SO far i'm thinking of doing something liek this so i can use a custom field for those pages i need to update mnaually:

    <?php 
//Attempt to get page one of a reviews url for social bar on extra review pages.
$social-field=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'social_url', true);
//if isset & not blank else use $post->ID
$social-field=(isset($social-field) && $social-field!='')?$social-field:the_permalink();
    ?>

Comment: posted in top now because i can't work out how to post clear code here!

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. You just need to determine a way to get a canonical URL on your end. Only you can decide how that logic is supposed to work.

Comment: i think my method will have to do as I'm not a very skilled programmer, i wouldn't know how to implement a more logical solution, sadly.

Comment: @Jim Actually yesterday i made a plugin for my wordpress blog, same that you want(with google+, twitter), because it is a bad practice to change direct in codes, because if you will change the template then you didn't find that functionality as well.

Comment: i have a follow up question: the first paragraph of code works, but how do i add this to functions.php? Possible?