# Facebook share button with meta tags

Tags: php, facebook

I am having list of multiple product displayed on a page. I want to give facebook share button for each button individually.And when user share such a product only image and description of that particular product should appear in facebook share. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373973/same-facebook-like-button-over-multiple-pages/9374061#9374061

Answer (score 0):

In your page where you have mentioned all product list in that page you write mane facebook share button code and i think you are using the same code.

```
<a name="fb_share" type="icon_link" 
   share_url="YOUR_URL">fb Share</a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

in this code there is one property i.e. `share_url` you put your product page url in that property and it will share the product image and product description on facebook.

Comment: Yes link is being shared but still no image or description is there :(